# Pulumi: ignore manually deleted resources during `pulumi up`

Tags: pulumi

I'm attempting to run a `pulumi up` command but it's failing because some of the resources that're being replaced were already manually deleted in the GCP Kubernetes dashboard. Is there a way to ignore the fact that these resources have already been deleted and continue with the update?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run `pulumi refresh` which will reach out to GCP resources and will update the current state file in Pulumi

Answer (score 6):

Use `pulumi state delete <urn>` to inform pulumi that the resource has been deleted.

Alternatively, `pulumi refresh` to attempt an automatic resync.

Finally, you can manually edit the state with `pulumi stack export > mystack` and `pulumi stack import --file mystack`.